# Creating an alternative query equivalent to given query but without the use of CUBE

Tags: sql

Hi I am struggling with a question from my SQL course. We have to give an equivalent query from a given query but without the use of CUBE. Here is the given query:

```
SELECT row_number() over () as nr, sex, city, count(*) 
FROM players
GROUP BY sex, city WITH CUBE
ORDER BY sex, city
```

I have no idea how to even begin with this, I would be very grateful if somebody could help me with this. There is no output, but I have a pretty good idea of how the output would look like, I just can't seem to figure out a way to get the same output without the use of CUBE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT row_number() over () as nr, sex, city, count(*) 
FROM players
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (sex, city), (sex), (city), () )
ORDER BY sex, city
```

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, row_number is missing order by. Also, it is GROUPING SETS without '_'. Cheers!

Comment: @Vboka . . . The OP has `row_number()` is no `order by`, and the code appears to work for that query.  In some databases, the `order by` is optional.

Comment: You are correct, Postgres for example can handle GROUPING SETS  and order by is optional. Cheers! Did not know that.